# Always Getting Error on Jsonp callback from Google Place API despite receiving result

Tags: jquery, jsonp, google-places-api

I am trying to get the results from Google Place API with the help of JSONP callback.

I have so far succeeded in getting the response but it returns error in my code.

below is my code which calls the GooglePlace API

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonpCallback:false,
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Houston&sensor=true&types=(cities)&key=<Mykey>'
            })
            .done(function () {
           alert("success");
           })
          .fail(function (e) {
        alert("error"+e);
            })
   .always(function () {
alert("complete");
});

}
function localJsonpCallback(json) {
    if (!json.Error) {
       // $('#resultForm').submit();
        alert('fail');
    }
    else {
        alert('success');
    }
}
 </script>
</head>



<body>



<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<p>Click the button several times to see if the time changes, or if the file is cached.   </p>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

i get the response in JSON array.but it always goes to fail callback

The Error Message is :

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

"predictions" : [

please help me with the problem.

Comment: You'd think it would be obvious, but maybe you should tell us what the error message says ?

Comment: The Error Message is SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

"predictions" : [